# Linq to XML selecting children list

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

An example XML file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<game>
    <name>bomber</name>
    <behaviors-used>
        <behavior id="Bullet" version="1">Bullet</behavior>
        <behavior id="Fade" version="1">Fade</behavior>
        <behavior id="Flash" version="1">Flash</behavior>
        <behavior id="Sin" version="1">Sine</behavior>
        <behavior id="scrollto" version="1">Scroll To</behavior>
    </behaviors-used>
</game>
```

I have the query:

```
var data = (from item in loaded.Descendants("game")
            select new
            {
                name = item.Element("name").Value,
                behaviorlist = item.Element("behaviors-used").Value
            }).Single();
```

Which seems to work fine.  However, I need to now retrieve all the `<behavior>` elements in the `behaviorlist`.  I can't seem to do it like this:

```
var bq = (from c in data.behaviorlist select new { behaviour = c.Element("behaviour")});
```

(Throws invalid syntax errors).

How do I retrive all the behaviours and not only access their text but also the properties `id` and `version`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `behaviorlist` is not really a list right now - you want the elements not the combined text, so instead of using the `Value` property of the parent node, you should retrieve the `Elements` with name "behavior":

```
var data = (from item in loaded.Descendants("game")
            select new
            {
                name = item.Element("name").Value,
                behaviorlist = item.Element("behaviors-used").Elements("behavior")
            }).Single();
```

From the resulting list you can then easily retrieve the properties:

```
var bq = (from c in data.behaviorlist select new 
{ 
    id = c.Attribute("id").Value,
    version = c.Attribute("version").Value,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`id` and `version` are attributes of a `behavior` node:

```
var items =
    xDocument.Descendants("behaviors-used")
             .Descendants("behavior")
             .Select((w, i) =>
                new
                    {
                        Index = i,
                        Value = w.Value,
                        Id = w.Attribute("id").Value,
                        Version = w.Attribute("version").Value
                    })
             .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Was able to get this to work in LinqPad with your document:

```
  var data = (from item in loaded.DescendantsAndSelf("game")
            select new{
                       name = item.Element("name").Value,
                       behaviorlist = item.Element("behaviours-used")
                      }
            ).Single();

  var bq = (from c in data.behaviorlist.Descendants("behaviour")
            select new {
                         behaviour = c.Value,
                         id = c.Attribute("id").Value,
                         version = c.Attribute("version").Value
                        });
```

and yielded a sequence of 5 anonymous objects {behaviour, id, version}